# Powershell - Optimize CSV processing with nested JSON

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I'm not a developer nor an CSV expert. I was able to put this piece of code     together and it's doing the job.
To give you a quick overview, I needed to process some JSON data that is nested in a CSV. So I'm reading the JSON and I'm splitting it into extra columns, then I'm saving the CSV.

Now, my issue is that although this is working fine, I now need to process a 1.5Gb CSV file and I don't want the processing to take 2 days...

So if you guys could help me tweak my script so that it runs in a reasonable amount of time, I would be extremely grateful :)

```
$file = Get-Content -Path 'input.csv' | Select-Object -Skip 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_StreamingEndpointName -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_Id -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_AppServicePlanUri -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_ImageType -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_ServiceType -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_VMName -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_UsageType -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_DatabaseAccount -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_CollectionRid -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AdditionalInfo_ResourceCategory -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_displayName -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_ACCESSED-VIA-INTERNET' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_APP-NAME' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_APP-TYPE' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_APPTYPE -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_CHARGECODE -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_COMMENTS -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_COUNTRY -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_EY-REGION' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_IT-ENV' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_OWNER -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_OWNER-EMAIL' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_SERVICELINE -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tags_SUB-TYPE' -value $null
$file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tags_TECHCONTACTS -value $null

$count=1
ForEach ($line in $file) {
Write-Output "Processing line: $count"
$count++
try{
    if ($line.AdditionalInfo -ne $null -Or $line.Tags -ne $null){
        $line.AdditionalInfo_StreamingEndpointName = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).StreamingEndpointName
        $line.AdditionalInfo_Id = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).Id
        $line.AdditionalInfo_AppServicePlanUri = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).AppServicePlanUri
        $line.AdditionalInfo_ImageType = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).ImageType
        $line.AdditionalInfo_ServiceType = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).ServiceType
        $line.AdditionalInfo_VMName = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).VMName
        $line.AdditionalInfo_UsageType = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).UsageType
        $line.AdditionalInfo_DatabaseAccount = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).DatabaseAccount
        $line.AdditionalInfo_CollectionRid = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).CollectionRid
        $line.AdditionalInfo_ResourceCategory = ($line.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).ResourceCategory
        $line.Tags_displayName = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).displayName
        $line.'Tags_ACCESSED-VIA-INTERNET' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'ACCESSED-VIA-INTERNET'
        $line.'Tags_APP-NAME' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'APP-NAME'
        $line.'Tags_APP-TYPE' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'APP-TYPE'
        $line.Tags_APPTYPE = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).APPTYPE
        $line.Tags_CHARGECODE = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).CHARGECODE
        $line.Tags_COMMENTS = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).COMMENTS
        $line.Tags_COUNTRY = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).COUNTRY
        $line.'Tags_EY-REGION' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'EY-REGION'
        $line.'Tags_IT-ENV' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'IT-ENV'
        $line.Tags_OWNER = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).OWNER
        $line.'Tags_OWNER-EMAIL' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'OWNER-EMAIL'
        $line.Tags_SERVICELINE = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).SERVICELINE
        $line.'Tags_SUB-TYPE' = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'SUB-TYPE'
        $line.Tags_TECHCONTACTS = ($line.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).TECHCONTACTS
        }
    }
    catch {}
}

#write-output $info
$file | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Just use `Import-Csv`...

Comment: 1.5TB CSV!?  You're best off limiting the amount of processing you're doing at once by using `Get-Content` and limiting the count of lines read at once so you don't run out of memory, but that goes out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Sorry. I meant a 1.5 GB file (not TB). Fixed. Also, Using Import-CSV did speed up processing. Any other possible tweak?

Comment: skipping first 2 lines with "Import-CSV | select-object -skip 2" did not work anymore like "get-content | select-object -skip 2" did.

Comment: Honestly, at those file sizes I guess using PowerShell is the wrong tool. A dynamic language has benefits when writing code quickly, but at the expense of execution speed.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, powershell is the only language I have easily access to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Add-Member` has terrible performance.  So does saving everything to variables over and over.  You might have better luck just keeping everything in a single pipeline and using `Select-Object` with computed properties:

```
Get-Content -Path 'input.csv' | 
    Select-Object -Skip 2 | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv | 
    Select-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Property *,
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_StreamingEndpointName' ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).StreamingEndpointName}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_Id'                    ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).Id}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_AppServicePlanUri'     ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).AppServicePlanUri}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_ImageType'             ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).ImageType}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_ServiceType'           ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).ServiceType}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_VMName'                ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).VMName}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_UsageType'             ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).UsageType}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_DatabaseAccount'       ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).DatabaseAccount}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_CollectionRid'         ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).CollectionRid}},
        @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_ResourceCategory'      ; e = {($_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-JSON).ResourceCategory}},
        @{n = 'Tags_displayName'                     ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).displayName}},
        @{n = 'Tags_ACCESSED-VIA-INTERNET'           ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'ACCESSED-VIA-INTERNET'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_APP-NAME'                        ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'APP-NAME'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_APP-TYPE'                        ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'APP-TYPE'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_APPTYPE'                         ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).APPTYPE}},
        @{n = 'Tags_CHARGECODE'                      ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).CHARGECODE}},
        @{n = 'Tags_COMMENTS'                        ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).COMMENTS}},
        @{n = 'Tags_COUNTRY'                         ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).COUNTRY}},
        @{n = 'Tags_EY-REGION'                       ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'EY-REGION'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_IT-ENV'                          ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'IT-ENV'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_OWNER'                           ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).OWNER}},
        @{n = 'Tags_OWNER-EMAIL'                     ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'OWNER-EMAIL'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_SERVICELINE'                     ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).SERVICELINE}},
        @{n = 'Tags_SUB-TYPE'                        ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).'SUB-TYPE'}},
        @{n = 'Tags_TECHCONTACTS'                    ; e = {($_.Tags | ConvertFrom-JSON).TECHCONTACTS}} | 
    Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

It might also be faster to say:

```
Get-Content -Path 'input.csv' | 
    Select-Object -Skip 2 | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $AdditionalInfo = $_.AdditionalInfo | ConvertFrom-Json;
        $Tags = $_.Tags | ConvertFrom-Json;
        $_ | Select-Object -Property *,
            @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_StreamingEndpointName' ; e = {$AdditionalInfo.StreamingEndpointName}},
            @{n = 'AdditionalInfo_Id'                    ; e = {$AdditionalInfo.Id}},
            ...
    } | Export-Csv ...
```

That way you're only converting the JSON once per line.

However, I suspect to get decent performance you'll have to write something using .Net methods.  I'd suggest using [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.1) to parse the CSV for you line by line and possibly [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the JSON with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.  Even then, this isn't going to be super fast.  1.5 GB of has got to be several million lines.  You may be better off to import the whole CSV into SQL Server 2016+ and use a query there with the built-in JSON parsing.

Comment: Thx Bacon Bits. Your script is working fine and it's far better code than mine but performance did not really increase. It's taking roughly 2mns to complete for a 10Mb sample, so that gives 5hrs for a 1.5Gb file. I'll give  Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser a try but I think you're right. And since all this data is going to a data warehouse, I'll probably use SQL SSIS and C# to parse the file and get decent performance. Thanks everyone for taking time to answer! :)

Comment: Can something similar be done for CSV to nested JSON?